# queries are running slow after Too many connections error

Tags: mysql, database-connection, innodb

Couple of days ago i had persistent query running on my website which was taking couple of long minutes to complete ( i've run it about 3 time)

It nearly killed my database , everything slowed down and i got `1040 too many connections` when i tried to get data from couple of my tables (session and setting tables for example which are the most used tables in my website - nearly every page is using them ) , and the odd thing is i wasn't trying to get data via my website , i was trying to access them from phpmyadmin ! that means those table were unreachable

Any way i took the website down and deleted my session table and somehow it was fixed (of cures i've never run that query again ) .

First of all i want to know what append to those tables ? were they corrupted ? i understand that connection limit were reached but i thought i should not get that inside phpmyadmin

Second and most important thing is i feel my queries are running much slower now even though i dont get that error anymore and my connections are under 30 per page is that have something to do with Too many connections error that i got ? should i clear or empty something !?

Here is the query (each tables has about 50-60 000 rows )

```
SELECT 
u.id,  u.username , u.created_on , meta.full_name as fullname , meta.avatar , COUNT(s.val) as image_scores
FROM
   users u
       LEFT JOIN meta ON (u.id = meta.user_id)
       LEFT JOIN images i ON (u.id = i.user_id)
       LEFT JOIN score_history s ON (i.id = s.content_id)and s.content_type = 'image'
GROUP BY
   u.id
ORDER BY
   image_scores DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure too many connection problem is the cause for slow query. But here are some suggestions to find the reasons for slow query.

1. Run your query with explain. explain [your query]. By this you can see what indexes are being used and you can figure it out any fields require indexing.
2. Check your table is indexed properly. users.id, meta.user_id, images.id, score_history.content_id and content_type are the fields to be indexed.
3. Make sure query caching is enabled in your mysql server.

Apart from this, try to reuse the same connection to avoid too many connection problem or always close the connection after use.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using `Connection Pooling`

Comment: thank you , do you mean i can solve persistent connection problem so i wouldn't get the error anymore , with Connection Pooling or or i can get ride of slowness of queries cuzing by that error by using Connection Pooling ?

Comment: you can solve the too many connections error. slowness is depends on multiple causes. ex: complex nested queries with out indexes, load on database...